# How to stop GNU make from expanding dollar signs in MAKEFILE_LIST?

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

Running

```
echo -e "all:\n\techo '\$(value MAKEFILE_LIST)'" > /tmp/foo\$bar.mk
make -f /tmp/foo\$bar.mk
```

will print

```
echo ' /tmp/fooar.mk'
/tmp/fooar.mk
```

From this we see that `MAKEFILE_LIST` contains *expanded* file names.

How can I get the correct name of the Makefile (including the dollar signs)?

My version: GNU Make 4.2.1.

My motivation: Actually the dollar signs are part of the *path* to my Makefile. I can not rename that path, because it comes from a Samba share that the people who will run make have to use.

### Update

Filed to upstream as http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?50823.

### Update

Proposed patch available at https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?50823#comment1.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hack, but anyway: you could define the *make* variable `b=$$b`:

```
$ cat '/tmp/foo$bar.mk'
all:
        echo '$(value MAKEFILE_LIST)'
$ gmake -f /tmp/foo\$bar.mk b='$$b'
echo ' /tmp/foo$bar.mk'
 /tmp/foo$bar.mk
```

This doesn't prevent the expansion, but makes the expansion effectively a no-op.

Comment: OK as a hack. But I do not know where the dollar character is for other people (might be part of their path to the Makefile), and if they merely include my Makefile and want to use `$b` for something else.